# How to populate a local URL in razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a local URL I am passing to a view via the ViewBag that comes from the referrer URL property of the Request object:

```cs
var returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
else
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "/DefaultPath";
}
```

In the Javascript of a function called on the viewI want to reference this URL to call back to the referring page. How would I write the razor syntax to properly format the URL to use in a window.location redirect?

Answer (score 0):

The following mixed razor/javascript function solved my issue:

```js
function referral_url_redirect() {
    var url = "@Url.Content(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.ReturnUrl))";
    if (url !== "null") {
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```